# Does dart have a testing framework similar to Javascript's Jasmine?

Tags: dart

Is there any test framework in Dart that is as robust as [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/)

I did use [pub test](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test), but it is made me wanting something like Javascript's Jasmine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.dartlang.org/guides/testing and https://github.com/dart-lang/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [test package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test) that you used is as robust as Jasmine. It is backed by tests, can run tests on multiple platforms (VM/server, browsers, Flutter), allows tagging, skipping, grouping, filtering by name, and more.

In what areas do you feel that Jasmine is more robust?